# How does supervisord stop processes inside a Docker container (trap kill signals)

Tags: docker, supervisord

When you send a stop or kill command (with some specific signal, eg. HUP, TERM etc) to a docker container, how does supervisord intercept that signal and send it to its child processes?

How can I gracefully stop my process inside a container when using supervisord?

There are two properties that can be specified in the `[program:x]` section: `stopsignal` and `stopwaitsecs`. But it appears that there is no way to specify a custom shutdown/stop script (eg. tomcat_shuytdwon.sh or something alike). Some programs use a custom shutdown process to gracefully stop.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [supervisord documentation](http://supervisord.org/running.html) when you send a `SIGTERM` the `supervisord` process and all its child processes are shut down. So it automatically passes down the signals to its child processes. So a simple `docker stop` should be enough.

Comment: Hi @h3nrik! 
Nice! But it appears there is no way (at least in the program section configuration) to specify a custom stop script to stop my application. Imagine I need to call a specific stop script that do a cleanup task before end the app process.

Comment: No. Specifying a custom script that reacts on signals is not possible.

Comment: But when you wrap the commands that are executed in your container in a bash wrapper script, you can [trap](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) those signals and react on them within that script and also [forward](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146756/forward-sigterm-to-child-in-bash) them to the child processes wrapped by that script.

Comment: Hum! Good idea! I will try that approach...
Do you think it worth issue a feature request to Supervisord supports custom stop command/script? That make sense for you?

Comment: I don't think that they want to offer that possibility. Traps could kind of "hijack" the whole signal handling. So they probably want to stay safe to and prevent users from doing so.

Comment: I tried to issue a new request [issue #639](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/639) but it was duplicated one :-/.
As you suggested they will not provide such feature: [Supervisord issue #147](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/147)